# Which are my windows partitions

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows, uninstall, gparted

Because of dual boot with kubuntu and windows I have [7 partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeQMX.png) on my hard drive (see the picture).

Now I want to delete all windows partitions to remove windows. I know that I have to keep 4 and 7. I am not too sure about removing 1 and 2. Which partitions are save to remove? Thanks for your help!

Comment: NTFS are Windows partitions, You also have two EFI partitions because you created another one . You can delete the first one.

Comment: Thanks! But what is partition 2?

Comment: It is a small ext4 partition. It doesn't seem to be used. probably the person who installed the system was struggling with understanding what is EFI partition and created some of them wrong.

Comment: Thanks again! This person must have been me, haha. This probably happened because of reinstalling windows.

Comment: Just a opinion, for updating bios/UEFI sometimes it is easier to do it with Windows.  You seem to have enough free space, so it depends on what you want to do.  Would leave the two EFI partitions alone, unless you know which is not being used.

Comment: Yes, that was also the reason why I reinstalled windows. Sometimes it just feels like wasted space. My final decision is still pending.

Comment: Better to just let Windows create its own partitions, then use Windows tools to shrink the NTFS partition to make room for Ubuntu. Just be sure to install both in UEFI boot mode. Only one ESP - efi system partition per drive, but you can have multiple FAT32 partitions.   Scroll down to see graphic of required partitions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations Vendors often add own recovery partitions in addition if pre-installed. Ubuntu UEFI:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thanks @olfred. But I already have both OS working quite well, just with 2 ESP, while it was the windows installer that has made the second one... Do you think I need to change something (if I want to keep both OS)?